# Find and remove array value using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the data I want to find using device array value 1 for and that object and removes that value from the device array.

find using device array value 1 and remove that value from the array

This is my current object:

```
[ 
 {
    "devices": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "eui": "A5AC840871F01D65",
    "key": "5BCBF770D2B43638860F7DA3733ED1B3",
    
  },
  {
    "devices": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ],
    "eui": "A5AC840871F01D65",
    "key": "5BCBF770D2B43638860F7DA3733ED1B3",
    
  }
]
```

the expected output is :

```
 {
    "devices": [
      "2"
    ],
    "eui": "A5AC840871F01D65",
    "key": "5BCBF770D2B43638860F7DA3733ED1B3",
    
  },
  {
    "devices": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ],
    "eui": "A5AC840871F01D65",
    "key": "5BCBF770D2B43638860F7DA3733ED1B3",
    
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$pull` for that. Here:

```
db.collection.update(
    { devices: "1" },
    { $pull: { devices: "1" } }
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItZwZdtzjO5